# Threaded Flask app gives OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use in Jenkins job

Tags: python, flask, jenkins, pytest, port

I am starting my Flask app in the thread and when I test it in local environment it works perfectly but whenever I run on Jenkins it gives an already in use error.

Here is my main test application to start in jenkins pipeline

```
python3.8 -m pytest -n 1 --reruns 1 -v -m Smoke --tb=short --instafail --durations=0
```

then inside the pytest_collection_finish i use

```
flask_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_flask_app)
flask_thread.daemon = True
flask_thread.start()
wait_for_trigger()
```

and here is my flask codes

```
from flask import Flask, request
from threading import Event
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple
import logging

app = Flask(__name__)
test_ready_event = Event()
logging.basicConfig(filename='flask_thread.log', level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')


@app.route('/trigger', methods=['GET'])
def trigger_test_continue():
    test_ready_event.set()
    print("Trigger received. Signalling pytest to continue.")
    logging.info("Trigger received. Signalling pytest to continue.")
    return "Continuing tests.", 200


def run_flask_app():
    logging.info("Starting Flask app.")
    run_simple('0.0.0.0', 5055, app, use_reloader=False, use_debugger=True)


def stop_flask_app():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()
    logging.info("Flask app stopped.")


def wait_for_trigger():
    print("Waiting for the trigger to continue tests...")
    logging.info("Waiting for the trigger to continue tests...")
    test_ready_event.wait()
    print("Trigger received. Continuing with tests.")
    logging.info("Trigger received. Continuing with tests.")
```

Error

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/var/lib/path/execution_stopper.py", line 22, in run_flask_app
    run_simple('0.0.0.0', 5055, app, use_reloader=False, use_debugger=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 1052, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 996, in inner
    srv = make_server(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 862, in make_server
    return BaseWSGIServer(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 740, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

when i run this in jenkins machine

```
sudo netstat -tulpn | grep :5005
```

gives

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5005            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1636790/python3.8
```

Comment: Ports are finite resources. Only one process can listen on the same interface(s)+port. If another app (or another instance of your app) is already occupying the port, you're going to run into this issue. This will be especially problematic if your Jenkins server is allowed to run multiple workloads at the same time. Run `lsof -i:5055` to find the process using the port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ones who has faced same issue i simply changed my flask code to this

```
app = Flask(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(filename='flask_thread.log', level=logging.INFO,
                    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

@app.route('/trigger', methods=['GET'])
def trigger_test_continue():
    logging.info("Trigger received. Signalling pytest to continue.")
    stop_flask_app()
    return jsonify({'status': 'success', 'message': 'Continuing test execution'}), 200


def run_flask_app():
    logging.info("Starting Flask app.")
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5005, debug=False, use_reloader=False)


def stop_flask_app():
    func = request.environ.get('werkzeug.server.shutdown')
    if func is None:
        raise RuntimeError('Not running with the Werkzeug Server')
    func()
    logging.info("Flask app stopped.")
```

and in the main application

```
flask_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_flask_app)
flask_thread.daemon = True
flask_thread.start()
flask_thread.join()
```